# Why do we count external pressure to calculate work done by gas instead of using internal pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, gas

Does internal pressure remain constant while doing work on surrounding or we ignore it? And when work is done on system we still count external pressure

Comment: In a rapid irreversible gas expansion, do you think that the gas satisfies the ideal gas law?  If not, how would you calculate the internal force on the piston?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work is defined with respect to the external pressure because it is the changes in external conditions that precipitate the changes to the internal state of the system. When we calculate work, we want to know how much work is done on or by some system of interest, so this convention is sensible. To your question about the internal pressure, typically it changes smoothly as the system undergoes whatever process we are talking about. For instance, if the pressure inside of a chamber under a piston is greater than the external (essentially constant) atmospheric pressure, if we allow the piston to move then it will expand the volume of the chamber until the internal and external pressure are the same and the system reaches equilibrium. But the internal pressure will be different than the initial pressure and will be getting closer to the final pressure at any given moment along the way.

In the special case that the internal and external pressures of the system are effectively the same at every step along some transformation, we call the work done “reversible.” Technically this is a hypothetical process, as we can never truly vary the external pressure that smoothly, but you could imagine lowering a piston over a gas chamber by adding individual grains of sand until you had doubled the internal pressure of the gas chamber. This would approximate a reversible process.

All of this discussion is part of the broad field of thermodynamics, so I suggest taking a look at a thermodynamics text for more details. [Atkin’s Physical Chemistry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198769865) is a very commonly used text in the chemistry community for this subject.

Comment: why was this down voted?

Comment: A question I am asking myself.